# Windows Runtime UI component

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I've heard about Windows Runtime Components, but seems like they are not applicable to UI components. Is it possible to create cross platform UI component (for example C#+xaml based component) which will run across all the projections C#, C++, javascript? I know projections are very different and need special environment to run, but if it's possible to create hybrid non-UI components maybe it's possible to create cross-platform UI components.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create components which expose UI to XAML apps, but you cannot create components which expose UI to JS applications - that's because the JS UI stack is dramatically different from the XAML rendering stack.

Comment: Are there any limitations on XAML UI components or I just create C#-XAML component as I used to do and just add reference from C++ application?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of - create a C# or C++ XAML component, then you can add it to your C++ or C# project - as long as it's XAML, it should just work (either C++ consuming XAML or C# consuming C++)

Comment: I've watched two guys session on build and they stated about WinRT objects: "Inheritance can only be used for XAML controls,all other types must be sealed." So, from this statement we can conclude that it's possible. http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/BUILD/BUILD2011/TOOL-531T And now I'm totally puzzled. I've tried to create component, but was unable. Maybe I missed something from this statement?

Comment: If you use the C# or C++ authoring experience, your types must be sealed. If you use the WRL+IDL authoring experience (low level), you can create unsealed types. Right now it's challenging to author WRL+IDL classes, but that should become easier in the future. 

It's important to remember that you CAN create sealed UI controls using C# and C++/CX.